# VBA document.all.item only works on username but not password

Tags: vba, excel, url

First, here's the code:  (the code are no different from standard codes for vba-open-website if that save you time reading, I placed a **<---------HERE** to indicate where I put my password)

```
Sub Login_2Wiki()

Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer
 Dim ieDoc As Object
 Dim ieTable As Object
 Dim clip As DataObject
 Dim iusr As Object
 Dim ipwd As Object
 Dim iform As Object

'create a new instance of ie
 Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer

'you don’t need this, but it’s good for debugging
 ieApp.Visible = True

'assume we’re not logged in and just go directly to the login page
 ieApp.Navigate "https://xxx.xxxxx.com/login.action?"
 Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
 Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

Set ieDoc = ieApp

'fill in the login form – View Source from your browser to get the control names
 With ieDoc
 Set iform = .Document.getElementById("login-container")
 Set iusr = iform.Document.getElementById("os_username")
 iusr.Value = "guest"
 Set ipwd = iform.Document.getElementById("os_password")
 ipwd.Value = "abc"

 .Document.getelementsbyname("loginButton")(0).Click
 End With
 Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
 Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop


'close 'er up
 ieApp.Quit
 Set ieApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

and Here's part of the source code on the webpage (it is a **Atlassian Confluence** page if that matters):

```
<div class="field-group
"
    >
<label id="os_username-label" for="os_username">
Username
    </label>

            <input type="text" name="os_username" id="os_username" class="text   " placeholder="Username" data-focus="0"     />
                  </div>                        

<div class="field-group">
<label id="os_password-label" for="os_password">
Password
    </label>
<input type="password" name="os_password" id="os_password"  class="password " placeholder="Password"  />
              </div>
```

Problem: the code only filled the username but not password on the webpage.  It gives no errors.  Also I notice there is a **data-focus = "0"** in the source view of the webpage, and wonder if that's the thing causing the problem.

> EDIT: I've replace **.Document.all.Item**  with
>   **.Document.getElementById** method, althought the code *can* find the element os_password (no errors), it fails to assign value to it.  os_username is working as before.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
With .Document.getElementById("os_password")
    .Focus()
    .Value = "abc"
End With
```

Comment: @TimVilliams Hey Tim, the .Focus() gives syntax error, that's only for VB.net maybe?

Comment: @TimVilliams I edited with .Focus() = True, which removes the syntax error but the password field is still empty

Comment: I can't make any more suggestions without seeing the complete page source.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I wish I can show you more but unfortunately I cannot do it.  Thanks for your input anyways

Comment: If I had the page in front of me, I would drill into the **Inspect Element** and use the console to investigate the *class="password"* in the CSS to see just what made that special.

Comment: @Jeeped thanks I will look into that, but there shouldn't be much except a bunch of javascripts (that doesn't affects the password)

Comment: "except a bunch of javascripts" - those are probably *why* your code is not doing what you want...

Comment: So Tim do you mean it is possible to have javascript that prevents assigning value to the element, or in any ways preventing us from targetting the correct element?

Comment: Yes - that could be done, but without the full source it's impossible to verify.  I did have a thought that it might be not possible to set the value of a "password" type input from VBA, but I just tested (IE9) and it worked fine, so something else is blocking your attempt.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that the focus has anything to do with your problem. That would be like saying that you could not `Range("B1") = "abc"` if A1 was the *ActiveCell*. As long as you are directly transferring the string to the `.Value` property, focus should not be an issue. If you were sending keystrokes then perhaps focus becomes important but we aren't going to do that.

I have run into a similar situation which a login page that was multiple purpose. The same 'landing page' had separate login forms for both buyers and sellers. I suspect that a close examination of the HTML behind that page will show that there are in fact two elements with identical Names/IDs (e.g. *os_password*). Further to all that, the `.Document.all.Item("something")` method can be used for either names or IDs; not the most definitive method of assigning a value. It would seem that you are setting something identified as *os_password*; just not the right *os_password*.

If this is the situation, you will have to address the password input as a child of the form you want to process, not of the entire document body. If your form had an ID of *Second_Form* then you would access the input fields like this:

```
    dim eFRM as MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    set eFRM  = ieApp.document.getElementById("Second_Form")
    eFRM.getElementById("os_username").Value = "guest"
    eFRM.getElementById("os_password").Value = "abc"
    'don't use names to locate elements - horribly unreliable
    eFRM.submit
```

Comment: Hi Jeeped thanks for your answer.  I did a search on the entire source page and those 4 'os_password' shown on the question are the only match.  Also, both os_username/os_pasword are under the same form "loginform".  I used your code and it gives me error 438 - Obj doesn't support this property or method on the .Value lines

Comment: Oh well - that was my 2¢. On rare occasions even a blind man can hit a bullseye but this isn't one of them.

Comment: no your approach is definitly correct - to target the correct group before assigning.